# Web Service Example - both Android and Server portions

Tags: android

I am looking to create a simple service to learn calling a service from android.
What I want to do is an app to call a system over the web provide some parameters and the system respond.  Very simple (hopefully)

But I want to build both ends.. not just the android end.

What tools would the community recommend that are industry standard and hopefully easily accessible.
I am hoping TomCat can do the hosting, but don't know if this should be a JSP or EE application.

Can anyone point me to an email of setting this up, again with both sides.

Hopefully Tomcat is a decent enough server to be both easy to setup and robust enough if enough calls are made to it.

Once that is done then I only need to do the android portion with Ksoap or anything else that is recommended.

Thanks in advance and I hope this is not too general a question.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Apache CXF for a server. It does pretty much everything that you need in a web service. It does have a client part, but so far, I have implemented web services on Android myself, rather than using libraries. But that was a while ago, maybe today libs are better customized for Android.

Comment: Actually, any server that has PHP will do. Use httpGet or httPost on the phone and read the info at the server side. With get it world be http://my.site?parm1=this&parm2=that from the phone. PHP would get the parameters with $_REQUEST. PHP would then build the response screen and send it.

Comment: "any server", that depends on how you interpret "web service". Strictly speaking, that is SOAP, and CXF is best for that. For just an api, any server sofware will do. If you want to use Java, you can use Restlet, which is very lightweigt and easy to use.

Comment: For enterprise level work, selecting specialized environments is great. However, for the small business or individual, you can get an Apache server with PHP and MySQL for about $100 a year. I do and I have a set up where I have PCs and Androids talking back and forth with XML. Works for me.

Comment: With PHP it's harder to make secure applications. If you're a relatively unexperienced coder, you're better off with Java, for that reason. Also, if you use Restlet, you save time compared to using php.

Comment: Okay. With Tomcat you're right. I'm a consultant and most businesses that aren't running enterprise level shops don't use Tomcat. I have to keep my eye on portability.  My clients typically have MySQL, PHP, Pearl, and Python. It's simple for me to set up my WAMP and test on my PC for those environments. Also, the client isn't worried that if I'm not available, another contractor can be found that will understand what I've written for them.

Comment: I downloade apache cxf (please remember never used it before) but am I correct in assuming to have this work I have to have tomcat server installed first.  So the over all setup would be tomcat with CXF running in it and me deploying apps to that?

Comment: Actually, you can use Tomcat or Jetty or any server, I prefer Jetty, but the industry standard is Tomcat.